# ID of each entity in AST given by clang

Tags: c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

When printing out the AST of a source code file, e.g.

```
int main() {
    return 4 + 5;
}
```

with `clang --cc1 -ast-dump`, I get:

```
TranslationUnitDecl 0x555a96835da8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
...
`-FunctionDecl 0x555a96893ab8 <tests/0.c:1:1, line:3:1> line:1:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x555a96893c10 <col:12, line:3:1>
    `-ReturnStmt 0x555a96893c00 <line:2:5, col:16>
      `-BinaryOperator 0x555a96893be0 <col:12, col:16> 'int' '+'
        |-IntegerLiteral 0x555a96893ba0 <col:12> 'int' 4
        `-IntegerLiteral 0x555a96893bc0 <col:16> 'int' 5
```

what does each ID (e.g. `0x555a96893ab8`) beside each entity mean?

Comment: Just guessing here, but it looks like a pointer, so perhaps it's simply `this` of the node?

Comment: Ah, it's possible. I didn't think of this. I will check it out, thank you.